# Safe transaction consumes too many redis client connections

Tags: gnosis-safe

I've installed the Safe Global infrastructure locally and incorporated some monitoring on it. I've realised that the `safe-transaction` component which is configured to work with the Gnosis Chain has opened more than **400 Redis client connections**. It looks like there is not a pool of connections and every time opens a new one.

The infrastructure is fresh install and still not being used by end users.

```
REDISCLI_AUTH=$REDIS_PASSWORD redis-cli CLIENT LIST | sed -n 's|.*addr=\(.*\)\:.*|\1|p' | sort | uniq -c

    434 10.2.89.158
      1 127.0.0.1
```

Here is the dashboard from Grafana showing this behaviour
[image]

Has anyone find this issue as well?

Best regards,

Comment: I think it's better report issues like this to Safe issue tracker, as this sounds like an internal issue with the software.